# cordova build ios does not create ipa file

Tags: ios, cordova, build, ipa

I am building cordova project for iOS, build log seems fine however I can't find any ipa file generated:

```
$ npm run cordova platform add ios
$ cat Build.json
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "**************",
            "packageType": "development",
            "automaticProvisioning": true,
            "buildFlag": [
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO"
            ]
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "****************",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "automaticProvisioning": true,
            "buildFlag": [
                "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT = YES",
                "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=NO"
            ]
        }
    }
}

$ npm run cordova build ios --release --device
```

[Build log](https://gist.github.com/melezhik/62c652f2b6736d13182b6c8d6981251d) looks fine.

However there is no ips files:

```
$ find . type f -name "*.ipa" | wc -l
0
```

Xcode version is 9.4
cordova-ios@4.5.5

Comment: From Xcode, Build > Archive should create the IPA file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build command should be run as `npm run cordova -- build ios --release --device` , double dashes are essential or else `npm run` does not pass `build ios --release --device` *as arguments* to `cordova` scripts. Uph, it's taken awhile for me to find it out.

Comment: Why are you using `npm run cordova ...` at all and not directly `cordova ...`? Do you have a special local setup of Cordova via your `package.json` you didn't mention?